# Variable not accessible inside ember each

Tags: ember.js

Why a controller's attribute not accessible inside each loop of ember? In our case **priorsAlphabetical** is a controller's attribute.

```
each conditionsAlphabetical itemController="booleanRadio"
        .col-xs-6.col-lg-5.option-value: .option-value-content
          partial "boolean-radio"
          if value
            a.add-note-link click="addConditionPrior this target='view'"
              span.icon-newspaper-alt.newspaper-color
          if-existing-prior param1=name param2=priorsAlphabetical
        a.add-note-link click="addConditionPrior this target='view'"
          span.icon-newspaper-alt
```

Here **priorsAlphabetical** is null inside each loop. However **priorsAlphabetical** is accessible outside **each** loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `each` helper is changing the current scope from the controller to the object it is currently looping through so inside the block it tries to retrieve priorsAlphabetical from each of the conditions objects.

```
#this context is the controller
each conditionsAlphabetical
  =name #this context is each condition
```

This is a somewhat confusing feature of the `each` helper and hence will be deprecated with Ember 2.0

To solve your problem use `each condition in conditionsAlphabetical` helper which will preserve the controller as the current scope.

```
#this context is the controller
each condition in conditionsAlphabetical
  =name #this context is still the controller
```

So in your particular case:

```
each condition in conditionsAlphabetical itemController="booleanRadio"
        .col-xs-6.col-lg-5.option-value: .option-value-content
          partial "boolean-radio"
          if condition.value
            a.add-note-link click="addConditionPrior condition target='view'"
              span.icon-newspaper-alt.newspaper-color
          if-existing-prior param1=condition.name param2=priorsAlphabetical
        a.add-note-link click="addConditionPrior condition target='view'"
          span.icon-newspaper-alt
```